# Responsive design squashing user image on profile page

Tags: bug, profile-page, responsive-design

When a user includes a large image in their "About me" section it appears to squash the user image on the left of the page. Reproduce here:
https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/54887/aegon

[image: Bug shown]

Reproduced in:

- Windows 10, Chrome v69
- Windows 10, Opera 55.0

---

Same user on this stack, same bug:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/307083/nsnoob

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveWerehog Looks to be the same one aye, will wait for the build to go out before closing though just to be sure as it is said to be an "edge case".